# Openpyxl "removed part drawing shape" and removed macros

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to edit a macro enabled workbook.  I have identical sheets for every day of the month and each sheet has an identical macro that is a Form Control button that prints out that sheet's contents and another separate sheet.  In total in my workbook I have nine Form Control buttons, one of which is unique and the other eight are identical.  After manipulating the spreadsheet with openpyxl (which does not touch the macros), and opening it, I will be greeted with the "removed part drawing shape" error; the other nine Form Control buttons will be fine, but the tenth one will be removed.  Below is the code for the macro anyways but I'm guessing this may be some other kind of VBA error or if its a quirk with form controls.

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .BlackAndWhite = True
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    If Sheets("ALT").Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
        With Sheets("ALT").PageSetup
            .BlackAndWhite = True
            .Orientation = xlPortrait
        End With
        Sheets("ALT").PrintOut
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

I expected to have each sheet operate identically and that openpyxl would save the file as normal.  Since then I have tried browsing the internet to troubleshoot the issue; most results I find are people stating that openpyxl does not support drawing but I believe those answers are outdated from a few years ago.  Even if lack of support were the case, I find it odd that nine of my ten Form Control buttons are functional while the last one is not.  One of the Buttons is named "Button 4" while the remaining eight are named "Button 1".  Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Are you opening the workbook with `keep_vba=True` ?

Comment: If I thought this was a bug I might report it. Or even check existing ones.

Comment: I apologize for not including it but yes, `keep_vba=True` is being used when opening the workbook